# wp shopping card site error "Call to undefined function pmpro_getOption() "

Tags: wordpress

I am still new to word press and I am getting the following error when I enter the url for the site:

"Call to undefined function pmpro_getOption()"

I have not changed any code but I have added a pluggin but the error message was not for the pluggin I added.

How do I get rid of this error.

Do I need to add any more information for someone to answer?

Before I started changing some of the options on the site I did make a backup.
I was thinking of removing the wp site from the hosting and reinstall it and restore the backup. I am not sure if there is an easier way than what I have just described.

thanks
maggs

Comment: Did you update, delete, or change any code in your theme/plugin

Comment: Log into your cpanel via ftp, and go to wp-content/plugins and delete the plugin 'Paid Membership Pro'. `pmpro_getOption()` is somehow missing in that plugin, this is why you are getting this error

Comment: Hi Pieter all I did was play with settings on the shipping. I didn't go can change any code.

Comment: I will do as you suggest. Besides deleting code is there any reason why code could become missing. This has happened to me once before. thanks maggs

Comment: I suspect that through the settings, you activated something that called for a the function `pmpro_getOption()`, which is not available in the free version. I hope you solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was.
I have 2 plugins Paid Membership Pro and PmPro Woocommerce and somehow the Paid Membership Pro was deactivated. I found this out by deactivating the PmPro woocommerce and the page displayed. Once I activated this plugin again the error occurred again. I then noticed that the Paid Membership Pro was deactived. Once this was activated again along with the PmPro Woocommerce the page displayed again and everything was back to normal.

thanks for your input.
maggs